# MacBook M1 | Blender Python; (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')

Tags: python, osx

I'm trying to import FreeCad inside Pyhton in Blender with the following code:

```
import sys

FREECADPATH = '/Applications/FreeCAD.app/Contents/Resources/lib/'

sys.path.append(FREECADPATH)

import FreeCAD
```

The code works in python outside of Blender. Inside Blender I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/FreeCAD.app/Contents/Resources/lib/FreeCAD.so,
 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/FreeCAD.app/Contents/Resources/lib/FreeCAD.so' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

I believe the problem is with Blender. How could I solve that?

Blender Version 3.1.2 (3.1.2 2022-04-01)

Comment: When running outside of Blender, you are probably running python with Rosetta.
The Blender Version for M1 has M1 compiled binaries and requires that the libraries will be too.

Comment: @HeziShahmoon I have this issue on a macbook pro m1 after `pip3 install cqparts` and trying to use the lib. How do we get it to install the correct architecture?

Comment: You should run the Blender's pip by the following command:
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.4/python/bin/python3.10 -m pip